# Why does deregistering a parathread fail while a crowdloan is open?

Tags: kusama, crowdloan

We registered a parathread to start crowdloan on kusama. The crowdloan just ended recently and we failed to get a slot. So I just used the same account to deregister, but it always fails with "Bad Origin". How can I deregister? We want to upgrade our chain for another crowdloan.

Answer (score 4):

Before you can deregister your parathread, you will need to end the crowdloan and have dissolved it. Otherwise the crowdloan still "holds a reference" onto the parathread.

Also be aware that one crowdloan can be used for multiple auctions if you failed to get a slot in the first try.

Answer (score 2):

I have written a post covering this specific topic, I think it might solve your doubts
[Deregistering my parathread using its manager account is not always possible](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1599/deregistering-my-parathread-using-its-manager-account-is-not-always-possible)